# open sqlite DB from Jest using react-native-sqlite-storage

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-native-sqlite-storage

I've a simple spec file to run JEST:

```
describe('config', () => {
  it('should be able to open database', () => {
    console.log(SQLite);
    SQLite.openDatabase(
      {
        name: 'TestDB',
        createFromLocation: '~/www/test.db'
      },
      () => console.log('success'),
      () => console.log('fail')
    );
  });
});
```

I want to write test which can open a pre-populated test.db (created using DB Browser for SQlite). DB is within ./www/test.db relative to the location of spec file. When I run SQLite.openDatabase, it fails with following error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined**

Eventually, I want to write a library to access data from sqlite as needed by a react-native app. However, this is the basic test which blocks further work.

Comment: Just to update my question, I couldn't find any way to do so. Eventually, I opted for custom mocks which imitate JEST functionality a lot. I can also use json files or real sqlite database using sqlitedb library (which works fine in opening database)